# md5sum of image and sd-card partition differ

Tags: raspberry-pi, dd, sd-card, hashsum

I am creating an image of an sd-card partition (dd) and eventually the checksum (md5sum) of the image and the partition are not the same.
What am i doing wrong?
My sd card is inserted into an external reader but not mounted.

```
sudo fdisk -l
  Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
  /dev/sdc3       30644224 250347519 219703296 104.8G  b W95 FAT32

Creating the image:
  sudo dd if=/dev/sdc3 of=/home/pi/part3.img bs=8M

Creating checksums:
  sudo md5sum /dev/sdc3
  sudo md5sum /home/pi/part3.img
```

Comment: Possibly a partial read within did? Are image and partition actually the same number of bytes long? Also, if this is a long-used SD card: yeah, uncorrected errors do happen on cost-conscious flash devices

Comment: @Ben Are there any read/write errors showing up in `sudo dmesg`?

Comment: @MarcusMüller: 1) Yes, the byte length is identical (fdisk and ls). 2) Yes, the SD card has been used 1 year in a raspberry pi. When i run "diff" (partition and image) it tells me they differ. When i run "cmp -l" i get a long list of differing bytes

Comment: @JamesRisner indeed, there are a few lines:
`[  308.418423] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc3, logical block 393216, lost sync page write
[  308.418427] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sdc2-8.
[  308.418428] Aborting journal on device sdc3-8.
[  308.418430] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc3, logical block 393216, lost sync page write
[  308.418431] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sdc3-8.
`

Comment: So, an unreliable storage medium not giving the same bits twice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SD is dead or dying (see more below), you will need to replace it. I’ve included some advice on what to use instead:

Using a SD card for a Raspberry Pi will drastically reduce their life expectancy. There are designed for 15 years of camera use, but with a RPi you will be writing logs tens if not hundreds of times a day. Helium miners are an example of using a RPi system where writes are common. They [they use eMMC instead](https://simeononsecurity.ch/other/replacing-nebra-outdoor-indoor-miner-emmc-key/) of SD cards, or 64 GB when they are forced. Most of the 64 GB is unused and there for more endurance.

If you have used this for a year, without changing the way the operating system writes to the disk, then your SD card has prematurely failed due to increased use.

I'd recommend replacing with a 64 GB SD card, and [implement as many of these recommendations as you can](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/169).

A dead or dying SSD or Hard Disk can be a result of [bit rot](https://getprostorage.com/blog/bit-rot-stop-destroying-your-data/), defects in the [controller firmware/microcode of the disk](https://blog.elcomsoft.com/2019/01/why-ssds-die-a-sudden-death-and-how-to-deal-with-it/), or your [hard drive controller in the system](https://techlogon.com/troubleshooting-a-faulty-sata-port/). There are even [utilities designed to repetitively read](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=recoverdisk&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+13.1-RELEASE&format=html) the same block until the read succeeds.

Comment: How is this related to my question? If the data is already written, shouldn't creating an image (=reading SD card) and reading for creating the checksum return the same result? Independently of any wear levelling logic. Thank you for your explanations regarding general use of an SD card on the raspberry pi. I will rethink what i can adapt from the provided link.

Comment: When ssd start to fail, is generally when they are out of wear/replacement blocks. So future writes are corrupted. You write X and read back Y.

Comment: This is advice for future use to avoid the situation you are in now. The only fix for your situation is replacing the SD

Comment: But, I am not writing data to my sdcard at the moment. I am just reading data. First, to create an image and second to calculate the checksum. So,  I am reading twice and getting two different results. Can a corrupted card be the reason?

Comment: @ben yes and that is common. Another reason is controlling defects with the sd, ram in the system defective. But If the issue is localized to the sd it’s likely the  sd.

Comment: I replaced the sd card with a new one and now it works as expected. The checksum of my image (created by dd) and the checksum from my SD card device are identical. I still don't understand why reading twice can result in two different results, but it's now very obvious to me, that thats the case.

Comment: Added a couple links discussing disk failure states. But it basically boils down to when the hardware is failing there are a lot of states where reading the same block multiple times hoping to get the correct data from the disk.

Comment: @Ben the nature of bitrot is that it might happen when you read, rather than when you write. the write could be perfectly successful as far as the OS can tell, but every time you read, something slightly different comes back - that stuff being read in this case is unreliable (rotten). Or it could be the other way -- the write fails  and, in this case, the OS will probably complain at the time